# Why does my network not learn a single image perfectly?

Tags: neural-networks, classification, overfitting, convolution, transfer-learning

I have a convolutional neural network that uses Resnet(18,34 or 50 doesn't matter) as the backbone and pretrained weights from ImageNet.When I try training it with a single image for 50 or so epochs, the loss first goes down to zero and stays there but after a while it spikes to very high values. Is this common and if it is, why? Theoretically, it should overfit the image right? The model should be like a function that spits out the same result for any image after a while.

Note: I'm training for classification

Comment: Could you show us a concrete example?

Comment: There are a number of alternative networks called ResNet. Which one are you using?

Comment: @Sycorax it does not matter. I used 3 different ResNet blocks. 18, 34 and 50. But each time, the network while training with one single image would go to almost zero and then jump suddenly to a large value.

Comment: If I had to guess, my guess would be that the loss does not decrease to exactly zero, but instead is just smaller than whatever decimal representation you're choosing for `print`. Then a numerical precision issue somewhere causes the division by a very small number, so the gradient is not computed accurately, so the parameters are updated incorrectly.